# geopandas - How to spatially join based on maximally overlapping feature

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a gdf of climate zones in CA and one of counties. Multiple climate zones often overlap a county, but I want to assign a county to be the climate zone that takes up the most area in a county.

Below is my code thus far, but it oddly says only climate zone 16 overlaps any counties, so there is a big problem.

```
import geopandas as gpd

counties = gpd.read_file('tl_2017_us_county/tl_2017_us_county.shp')
counties = counties[counties['STATEFP'] == '06']

climate_zones = gpd.read_file('BuildingClimateZonesMap/CA_Building_Standards_Climate_Zones.shp')
counties.crs = climate_zones.crs
test = gpd.sjoin(climate_zones, counties, how='left', op='intersects')
```

Here are the links to the data:
http://www.energy.ca.gov/maps/renewable/building_climate_zones.html
https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2017&layergroup=Counties+%28and+equivalent%29

Comment: I ran your code. If you run "test['Zone'].values", do you not get 73 values that vary from 1-16? Almost all of them are indeed 16, but all the other zones are represented (meaning they overlap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore my comment. After looking through the "test" dataframe and your code, I think I see what's happening.

When you run the line

```
counties.crs = climate_zones.crs
```

you are simply telling Geopandas to interpret the counties CRS as the climate_zones CRS, but you are not actually reprojecting it, which you need to do before intersecting. Change that line to this:

```
counties = counties.to_crs(climate_zones.crs)
```

and you'll see that "test" contains what you expect.

Note that when I ran the intersection, I got the message

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in ? (vectorized)  outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
```

I'm not sure if that's a critical problem or not, but you should make sure the test geodataframe is correct (pull it up in QGIS). I looked at it in QGIS and it seemed fine--all the Climate Zones were there and based on the few spot-checks I did, their intersecting counties were correct.

Comment: thanks. yea I have it on left join, so that's why you see all climate zones. is there a way to then get the area of the intersecting regions and only select the max? I was able to do it without spatial join, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it with spatial join

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a one-liner spatial join. Probably you just need to use the .area method (e.g. test.geometry.area.values) to compute areas for each of the intersected polygons, then loop through all the counties and choose the climate zone with the largest area. Be sure to reproject your intersected dataframe to an Equal Area Projection (so that areas are preserved and the comparisons are accurate).

Answer (score 2):

This function should work for this problem:

```
def max_area_attr_join(gdf1, gdf2, id_col, attribute_col):
    #spatial overlay
    s = gpd.overlay(gdf1, gdf2, how = 'intersection') 
    s['area_ov'] = s.geometry.area
    
    gb = s.groupby(id_col)[['area_ov']].max()
    
    #add the column 'area_ov' to the original gdf.
    gdf1 = gdf1.merge(gb, left_on = id_col, right_index = True) 
    
    #drop extraneous columns from the joined gdf
    s = s[['area_ov', attribute_col]]
    
    #merge the attribute column to the original gdf.
    gdf1 = gdf1.merge(s, on = 'area_ov')

    return gdf1.drop(columns = ['area_ov'])
```